# How value a List without IN operator

Tags: python, list, function

I have this Question:
Write a function is_member() that takes a value (i.e. a number, string, etc) x and a list of values a, and returns True if x is a member of a, False otherwise. (Note that this is exactly what the in operator does, but for the sake of the exercise you should pretend Python did not have this operator.)
my code:

```
def is_member(a):
    a = raw_input("Give a Number: ")
    b = ['hallo', '120', 'me']
    for i in a:
        if a[i] == b:
            return True
        else:
            return False
print is_member('a')
```

Mit IDLE console , I come : TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str .Where is the problem ?? . Very Thanks for yours help!

Comment: Look in the documentation, what type does `raw_input` return?  How do you convert that to an `int`?  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input.  What is `for i in a` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Usually when a specification says a function "takes a value", that means that the value in question is passed to the function as one of its arguments.  This leads me to believe that this should be a function of two arguments (with no `input` calls)

Comment: maybe `b[i] == a` or `if(a in b)`

Comment: @Arma the exercise asked a Value without IN.....#

Comment: Stop editing your question such that the formatting is corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a` is a `str` (string), next you use a `for` loop to iterate over the characters of that string?

You probably want to do it the opposite way. Either:

```
for i in b:
    if a == i:
        return True
return False
```

Or:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    if a == b[i]:
        return True
return False
```

Note that you **can't** `return False` in the `else` case: it is not because the *first* check fails, the remaining checks cannot eventually yield an element that is equivalent. You thus have to loop *through the entire collection* before you know for sure the element is not in the list*.

Comment: Very Thank for you answer and the correction...Can you splain me please because for i in b , and not for i in a , i will Python learn  , not only Copy ans Paste ....

Comment: I know now because can not a[i] to write , a are not a List , it is as you tell ,a string.... , List  is b..., very Thanks for your help!

Comment: @iratxe: no problem, we are here to help :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to use `raw_input` then you don't need the parameter of `is_member` because `a` always becomes the return value of `raw_input`.

Also `a` is a `string`, not `list`, so `i` is `string`.
Example:

```
>>> for i in 'abc':
...     print(i)
...
a
b
c
```

`is_member` should be:

```
def is_member():
    a = raw_input("Give a Number: ")
    b = ['hallo', '120', 'me']
    return a in b

print is_member()
```

or

```
def is_member(a):
    b = ['hallo', '120', 'me']
    return a in b

print is_member('a')
```

Comment: Although it is specified in the comments, the OP is not supposed to use the `in` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the for loop sets `i` to hold the values of `a` in turn, and so when you reference `a[i]`, it tries to find `a['hallo']`, which it clearly cannot. You simply need to replace `a[i]` with `i`, and then it should work perfectly.